# What is the best way to reorder SharePoint List items?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I'm currently working on a Web Part that renders specific elements which properties are taken from a SharePoint List.

I'm planning to add a Field in SP List that will allow the SharePoint user to enter a number to specify the Order in which the elements will be rendered.

**Question:** What is the best way to implement this (keeping in mind that user may enter the same value twice or omit a number in sequence without knowing it)?

**Example:** we have elements and their Order value: `A 1`, `B 2`, `C 3`, `D 4`, `E 5`.

If a user changes the Order value to: `A 1`, `B 4`, `C 3`, `D 4`, `E 5`, the elements should be rendered in order: `A`, `C`, `B`, `D`, `E`.

And if a user changes the Order value to: `A 1`, `B 7`, `C 3`, `D 4`, `E 5`, the elements should be rendered in order: `A`, `C`, `D`, `E`, `B`.

Comment: By "elements" you mean list items or list fields (columns)?

Comment: List Items. I already found a topic where someone asks about reordering List Fields but that's not what I need.

Comment: How do you retrieve the items? By SPQuery?

Comment: @banana For now (without ordering), I simply create a SPListItemCollection from List["Name"].Items and iterate through it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use `SPQuery`, it is also supposed to be more efficient.

When you use SPQuery you can specify `OrderBy` as you wish.

Here is an example of using it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534(v=office.14).aspx

Comment: I find your solution simple and elegant. I also found some more useful knowledge on this issue here: http://blog.qumsieh.ca/2008/11/06/how-to-write-an-spquery-to-sort-your-list It works well. Thank you! I would like to Vote Up your answer but sadly I don't have enough reputation...

Answer (score 1):

There is out-of-the box solution for list items reordering in SharePoint 2010.

http(s)://yousiteurl/_layouts/Reorder.aspx?List=ListGUID

After you reorder your items you can use CAML query to order by your items using item["Order"].

You can call this page in a modal dialog on you page or integrate this in the ribbon using custom actions.

More information how to do this can be found [here](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/mattlally/archive/2012/01/16/add-change-item-order-to-a-custom-link-list.aspx).

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Surely, good to know but for this specific issue banana's solution is more of what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a new `SPField` to store the list items order, you must be aware that this values will not be customizable per user. They are assigned to the list items and are the same for all the users.

I believe you should take a look at the [Creating a Web Part with Custom Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd584174%28office.11%29.aspx) topic. You could map the item IDs with a custom ordinal sequence, personalized per user. Then, you could override the default order and with the help of some client scripting, you could rearrange the items. Of course, things could get complicated when the items are displayed using pagination.

But the more realistic way to approach your requirement would be to create several fields (`CustomOrder1`, `CustomOrder1` etc) and subsequently, some custom views which are sorted based on these fields.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't very clear (I'm sorry for that) but in my question I wanted to focus on the idea of implementing the ordering itself without any per-user settings. But thanks for the link anyway, it might help me in future.

Answer (score 0):

This is the easiest solution. Activate linkedlist reorder button.
https://pgbhoyar.com/2013/05/15/how-to-reorder-sharepoint-list-items-using-custom-codepowershell-and-sharepoint-designer-in-sharepoint-2010-and-sharepoint-2013-2/